# Lower bound on $\prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers

I am wondering if a lower bound for

$\prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$

exists, where p is a prime.

My first instinct was to make this step (As one usually does for this kind of question)

$\prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)>\prod_{p-prime}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$

But I am not sure how to progress from here.

Comment: yes you can do that $\prod_p (1-1/p^2) = \frac{1}{\zeta(2)} = \frac{6}{\pi^2}$.

Comment: Could you please explain this slightly more. I am not very familiar with the Riemann-zeta function

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem

Comment: Furthermore, the lower bound $\frac6{\pi^2}$ from user1952009's comment is best possible: given any $c>\frac6{\pi^2}$, there exists $n$ divisible by so many of the first primes that $\prod_{p\mid n} (1-\frac1{p^2}) < c$.